# same file extention in vim been detected as different filetype and I didn‘t change anything.(neovim)

Tags: vim

I use `echo &filetype` for file I create yestoday with extension .tex and the result is `tex`,
but today when I create another .tex file ,this code will get filetype `plaintex`, and I check my .vimrc it didn't change.
I want to know why the file extension is same while filetype is not, how can I let them to be the same

Answer (score 1):

Even though the TeX formats are very different, but they all use the same `.tex` extension for their source files. Hence Vim tries to guess the correct format by some heuristics.

When nothing else helps Vim assumes it's a plaintex. You can add  `let g:tex_flavor = 'latex'` to your vimrc to change this.

Read also `:h g:tex_flavor` for more info.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had set this before and I don't undertand the meaning.